# Fama-Macbeth Regression in R: Error Insufficient number of time periods

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel-data

unfortunately i am a beginner in R.
I´d like to run a Fama-Macbeth regression on my dataset. My dataset is an unbalanced panel dataset of different fund over the time. My data is identified by a fund_id and a month_id. The following regression leads to the error below:

```
result_capm <-   pmg(flow_percent_lead1~alpha_capm_adj+tna_USD_adj+number_shr_cl_adj+front_load, data=Daten, index = c("month_id","fund_id"))
```

Everytime i try to run this regression, the following error appears:

```
Error in pmg(flow_percent_lead1 ~ alpha_capm_adj + tna_USD_adj + number_shr_cl_adj +  : 
Insufficient number of time periods
```

First i thought that maybe there are some fund_ids with too less obersavation to rund this kind of regression, so i tried to eliminate the fund_ids with less than 10 different month_ids, but this doesn´t work.

```
Length_month_ID <- aggregate(Daten$month_id,list(Daten$fund_id),length)
delete_fund_ids <- Length_month_ID[Length_month_ID$x<15,]
Daten <- Daten[!(Daten$fund_id %in% delete_fund_ids$Group.1),]
```

Unfortunately i have no further idea to fix the problem. Maybe does someone has an idea?